# Delay and rise/fall times in assign statements for real variables in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I need to write a uni directional analog switch in Systemverilog with some delay and rise and fall times.

```
input real in;
output real out;
assign #<delay> out = (enable === 1'b1)?in:0.0;
```

With above, I do not see any delay and output is exactly same as input with enable = 1. Is there a way I can add delays and rise/fall times to the above?

Comment: how did you look at the values? Are you modeling analog values? why `real`?

Comment: Yes Serge, I'm modeling analog values. I'm modeling a uni directional analog switch..

Answer (score 0):

rise/fall delays are not defined for anything other than integral values.

Comment: Thanks dave_59. Ya, I observed that. However, is there a way to realise the above?

Comment: `always_comb  out <= #<delay> (enable === 1'b1)?in:0.0;`

Comment: I believe that would help me realise the delays but not the rise/fall times. Can we also realise the rise/fall times too?

Comment: It does not make any sense to have a rise/fall delay with a real number. Why should there be a delay with a change from 0.000 to 0.001, but no delay with a change from 0.001 to 1000.0? (only zero to non-zero is considered a _rising_ edge)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that as per the rise/fall times as defined in verilog, it does not make sense. However, I'm trying to model as per the general definitions of rise/fall times i.e. in the above example, I intend to pass real signal 'in' to real signal 'out' when 'enable' = 1, but I want the output 'out' to rise from its current value to the final value (which is same as 'in) in finite amount of time.

Comment: Perhaps you want `always @* if (enable ===1) out <= #rise_delay in; else  out <= #fall_delay 0.0;`

Comment: I believe that would rather give me rise/fall delays and not rise/fall times. Please correct me and help me understand if I'm wrong. To re-frame my requirement, signal 'out' can start rising/falling immediately after enable changes from 0-1 and vice versa respectively, but it should reach its final value in finite non-zero time. This is equivalent to 'transition' filter in Verilog-AMS

Comment: OK, now you are making sense. Unfortunately, you can't do that in Verilog/SystemVerilog without writing a for loop to make all the discrete changes in your signal.